# Vue Router and VueJS reactivity

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I've got this code for my `vue-router`:

```
{ 
   path: '/templates/:id/items/:itemId', component: Item,
   name: 'item'
},
```

On the item object, I've got a computed property `templateId`:

```
templateId() {
   return parseInt(this.$route.params.id, 10);
},
```

The issue I have, is, each time I add an anchor to the url (clicking a link, INSIDE the `item` component), even if the component doesn't change, this property is computed again.

It means that all computed properties depending of `templateId` will be computed again.

**But the templateId value doesn't change at all.**

Here is a really simple jsfiddle to explain the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/1Lgfn9qh/1/

If I remove the watch property (never called), nothing is logged in the console anymore.

Can you explain me what's happening here?
Why the computed properties are recomputed, even if no values has been updated?
How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's causing this behaviour is the fact, that the `route` object is immutable in Vue. Any successful navigation will result in a completely new route object therefore triggering a re-computation of all computed and watched properties. See https://router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object for more details.

To solve this you can `watch` the route object and filter the relevant vs irrelevant changes for you there

```
watch: {
  '$route' (to, from) {
    if(to.path != from.path) { // <- you may need to change this according to your needs!
      this.relevantRoute = to
    }
  }
}
```

And then reference the manually set variable in your computed and/or watched properties

```
templateId() {
  return parseInt(this.relevantRoute.params.id, 10);
},
```

Comment: It makes sense, I understand why `templateId` is recomputed. But why `hugeTransaction` is computed again since `templateId` is not updated?

Comment: There is a difference in JS between objects being equal vs identical (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness). It might look to you like `templateId` hasn't changed (since it still has the same "content") but under the hood *it has changed*. It is a different object now and therefore it triggers Vue's change detection.